# Check for parameter in function - accept input value 0

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to validate if a parameter is present, see example code:

```
function Test-Function {

    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [Int64]$TestParam
    )
    if ($TestParam) {
       Write-Host "Parameter is present.."
       # Do stuff ...
    }
}

# Execute the function
Test-Function -TestParam 1
Parameter is present..

# Pass the value 0
Test-Function -TestParam 0
<no output>
```

Is there a way to fix this? The type must be an integer, not `[String]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [the `$PSBoundParameters` automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables) to inspect parameter binding results for the current invocation:

```
if($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('TestParam')){
    "Caller definitely provided an argument for -TestParam"
}
```

Note that an argument is considered bound regardless of whether the binding was *positional* or if it was explicitly bound by name:

```
function f {
  param(
    [Parameter(Position = 0)]
    $TestParam
  )

  if($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('TestParam')){
    "Caller definitely provided an argument for -TestParam"
  }
}
```

```
PS ~> f -TestParam 123
Caller definitely provided an argument for -TestParam

PS ~> f 123
Caller definitely provided an argument for -TestParam
```

In the second example, we never explicitly bind `123` to `-TestParam`, but because `TestParam` is the first positional parameter, 123 is bound to `$TestParam`, and thus `$PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('TestParam')` returns `$true`